# What is a good way to calculate $E|\frac{1}{n}\sum X_{i}|$?

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_{i}$ are a random sample of $n(0,1)$ variables, Berger and Casella asked me to evaluate the following:

1): $E(|\frac{1}{n}\sum X_{i}|)$.

2) :$E(\frac{1}{n}\sum|X_{i}|)$.

I think (2) is automatic since we have $$E(\frac{1}{n}\sum|X_{i}|)=\frac{1}{n}E(\sum |X_{i})=E|X_{i}|=2\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{0}xe^{-x^{2}/2}dx=-\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-u}du=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

However I do not know how to evaluate $$E(|\frac{1}{n}\sum X_{i}|)=\frac{1}{n}E(|\sum X_{i}|)=\frac{1}{n}E(\sqrt{(\sum X_{i})^{2}})$$

My thought was since $X_{i},X_{j}$ are independent, we should have $$E(\sum X_{i}^{2})=E((\sum X_{i})^{2})=E(\chi_{n-1}^{2})=2(n-1)$$ because $E(X_{i}X_{j})=Cov(X_{i},X_{j})=0$. So if I can calculate the variance of $|\sum X_{i}|$, then I can calculate the expectation of $|\sum X_{i}|$ as well. But it seems the variance is not easy.

A "brutal force" approach is to calculate

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}|\sum X_{i}|e^{-\sum \frac{X_{i}^{2}}{2}}dX_{1}\cdots dX_{n}$$And it seems an innocuous calculus problem. Nevertheless I am at lost how to evaluate it. So I decided to ask. Sorry the problem level is really low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The random variable $\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ has normal distribution, mean $0$, variance $\frac{1}{n}$. Call it $W$.

Now a calculation much like the one you did for the second problem will give $E(|W|)$.
The density function of $W$ is not hard to write down. One can then exploit symmetry as you did in the second problem. The integration is of the same kind.